# Boto3 get only S3 buckets of specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The following code sadly lists all buckets of all regions and not only from "eu-west-1" as specified. How can I change that?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="eu-west-1")

for bucket in s3.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:

    bucket_name = bucket["Name"]
    print(bucket["Name"])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="eu-west-1")
```

connects to S3 API endpoint in `eu-west-1`. It doesn't limit the listing to `eu-west-1` buckets. One solution is to query the bucket location and filter.

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

for bucket in s3.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    if s3.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['LocationConstraint'] == 'eu-west-1':
        print(bucket["Name"])
```

If you need a one liner using Python's list comprehension:

```
region_buckets = [bucket["Name"] for bucket in s3.list_buckets()["Buckets"] if s3.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['LocationConstraint'] == 'eu-west-1']
print(region_buckets)
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if the connection to a region but still listing everything is a feature or a bug?

Comment: It is not a bug. S3 was region neutral initially. So listing the buckets connecting to any region will list all buckets.

Comment: hm .. with the recent announcement for IA region specific deployment I hope this changes. I thank you for your help.

Comment: @lony the new storage class, One Zone-Infrequent Access, is no more "region specific" than all of the existing storags classes -- they are all region-specific.  One Zone-IA is an *object* attribute, not a *bucket* attribute.  No change should be expected, as all buckets are already constrained to a single region, and all regional endpoints have access to the global bucket directory (but not the contents of buckets in other regions).

Answer (score 5):

The solution above does not always work for buckets in some US regions because the 'LocationConstraint' can be null. Here is another solution:

```py
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

for bucket in s3.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    if s3.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-bucket-region'] == 'us-east-1':
        print(bucket["Name"])
```

The SDK method:

`s3.head_bucket(Bucket=[INSERT_BUCKET_NAME_HERE])['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-bucket-region']`

... should always give you the bucket region. Thanks to sd65 for the tip: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/292

Comment: do I need the check, or every time it is null it us-east? To reproduce this, is it enough to just create a bucket in us-east-1? As I so far did not encounter this problem.

Comment: Not sure, I just ran into this issue with a handful of us-east-1 buckets, as have others. I will be using this method going forward because it's the only one that I know works 100% of the time.

Comment: `Bucket=first_bucket` should be `Bucket=bucket['Name']` otherwise this example throws an error.