# Boto3: Get details of all available S3 Bucket details

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to list the metadata about all the **S3** buckets available in my AWS account using the boto3 client.

I tried below api:
 https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets but it just returns the bucket name and created date.

I am looking for more details like:

1. Bucket Region
2. Bucket status like Active
3. Bucket Id (if there is any)

It would be more helpful if I can get a single API which can return all these details as `describe_instances` of EC2 returns more metadata.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: There is no concept of a bucket "status". The bucket Id is its name. Can you provide more details about _why_ you need this information? We might be able to provide a better answer if we know more about what you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this post of some help!

1. S3 Region? - I don't think, S3 is region-specific anymore. Also, the bucket name is already a unique value.
2. As you can see in the same document you have below function for collecting a different kinds of metadata.

```
get_bucket_accelerate_configuration()
get_bucket_acl()
get_bucket_analytics_configuration()
get_bucket_cors()
get_bucket_encryption()
get_bucket_inventory_configuration()
get_bucket_lifecycle()
get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration()
get_bucket_location()
get_bucket_logging()
get_bucket_metrics_configuration()
get_bucket_notification()
get_bucket_notification_configuration()
get_bucket_policy()
get_bucket_policy_status()
get_bucket_replication()
get_bucket_request_payment()
get_bucket_tagging()
get_bucket_versioning()
get_bucket_website()
```

These are created just for the reason of segregating information that specifically required for user.

In my opinion, you are looking for `get_bucket_inventory_configuration` - Returns an inventory configuration (identified by the inventory ID) from the bucket.

This will also return ARN which is a unique id for all AWS resources.

A sample ARN looks like

```
'Bucket' :"arn:aws:s3:::10012346561237-rawdata-bucket"
```

Comment: Thanks @Sampath for the help. While creating a bucket AWS ask us to choose the region where bucket resides so I was referring to that region name.

Comment: @Imran, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814173/boto3-get-only-s3-buckets-of-specific-region for bucket region name

Comment: @Imran - yes previously. Today, this is how I am using for AWS lambda  - https://medium.com/@stephinmon.antony/aws-lambda-with-python-examples-2eb227f5fafe - But this is only for s3! I still agree with you, specifying is better!