# How to get the region of a boto3 S3 resource instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I instantiate a boto3 S3 `resource` like this (code simplified):

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import boto3


s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
    aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
    # NOTE: My config is:
        # [default]
        # region = eu-west-1
    region_name=os.getenv("region_name"),
)
```

How can I get the region to which the S3 resource is associated? Is there an attribute of the class / instance I can query?

I checked the [boto3 docs for the S3 Service Resource object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource) but couldn't find such an attribute. I also checked this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814173/boto3-get-only-s3-buckets-of-specific-region) but it relates to the `client` not `resource` object from boto3.

Context: I want to check the region so that I can ensure that my ~/.aws/config is being read to supply the region, since checking what `os.getenv("region_name")` returns `None` since I have no such environmental variable. If you can answer this question too, it's a bonus. As cited in the code, my config points to the *eu-west-1* region.

I'm new to using S3 programmatically inside Python (I've mostly used the AWS CLI) so please suggest edits to the question if necessary.

Comment: `aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")` - this is redundant as the SDK does this automatically. It does prevent config load from config file. See credentials search order here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials

Comment: Fair point @jordanm with the given information. Added context: This is an extract of a function which takes a s3_region_name argument then does `region_name=os.getenv("region_name") if s3_region_name is None else s3_region_name`. Thank you, your link is very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, every boto3 resource has a client in meta, so you can do this:

```py
s3_resource.meta.client._client_config.region_name
```

Comment: Alas, no joy: `NameError: name 's3_resource' is not defined`

Comment: @Hephaestus you have to define it, like in the question, first. Then this returns the client.

Answer (score -2):

You can check for the region via AWS Console (UI).
Goto: S3 -->  --> Properties tab, and you'll see the "AWS Region" of your bucket:

[image]

**EDIT**:
following your comment, maybe you're looking for [get_bucket_location](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_location):

> Returns the Region the bucket resides in.

Comment: I think this misunderstands the question. They want to programatically get the region name from their boto3 resource object.

Comment: Exactly as @jordanm says. I want to programatically get the region name from the boto3 resource object all within Python

Comment: @Anil `get_bucket_location` ?

Comment: This is the method cited in the related question I linked. The method you linked is a client method, not a resource method.